# How to rename multiple files keeping brackets - Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, file-rename, rename-item-cmdlet

I am trying to remove any words before content inside [*]

I have multiple files to rename for example 'ABC [1].txt, ABC [2].txt, ABC [3].txt' that I need to rename to '[1].txt, [2].txt, [3].txt'

I have a few hundred items to rename and wondered if this can be done in powershell.

However I can not find any information on doing this. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I would get rid of the brackets if I were using a lot of powershell.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by an easy regex replace:

```bash
$sourceFolder = "C:\path\to\your\dir"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter "*[*" | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace '.*(\[\d+\].*)', '$1'
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

**Explanation of the regex used:**

- **`.*`** - match 0 or more of any character.
- **`(\[\d+\].*)`** - Capturing group capturing 1 or more digits which are enclosed in `[]` followed by the **ext-name**.
- **`$1`** - is the substitution string which is captured above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) with a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), in which you can dynamically determine the new name for each given file based on its existing name (`$_.Name`) and outputting the new one.

In your case, the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) allows you to remove everything before the (last) `[` from the file name:

```bash
Get-ChildItem *.txt |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^.+ (?=\[)' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The above could result in *duplicate* target file names, and handling this case would require extra work.
- Not specifying a replacement operand with `-replace` is the same as specifying the *empty string*, which effectively *removes* what was matched.

  - E.g., `'foo' -replace 'o'` is the same as `'foo' -replace 'o', ''`: both result in `'f'`
- You could make the regex more robust, if needed; e.g.:

  - `$_.Name -replace '^.+ (?=\[\d+\]\.txt$)'`

    - For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/Dt3FQ3/1).
  - Or - to demonstrate handling the *base* file name and its *extension* separately:

    - `($_.BaseName -replace '^.+ (?=\[\d+\]$)') + $_.Extension`
- Input file names that don't match the regex cause `-replace` to return the input string as-is, which in turn causes `New-Item` to quietly skip such files (trying to rename a file to its existing name is a quiet no-op).

  - However, note that as of PowerShell 7.4.0 this only works with *files*, and not also with renaming *directories*, where an attempt to rename to the existing name causes an *error*.
  - Treating directories the same as files (quiet no-op if the new name is the same as the old) is the subject of [GitHub issue #14903](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14903),  which has been *green-lit*, but no one has stepped up to implement it yet.